# Data is returned from database, but also an exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-web-api

I have a method that gets data from a database. The data itself is a query which is supposed to be run against different databases. It works, but not really, because I see in the terminal that it writes the correct rows, but it also crashes and gives me an SqlException saying that the table is an invalid object, but it does exist.

I've tried to use a different table which I've used in a previous project, and it doesn't work either. It's my first time working with Web API, so perhaps I'm missing something.

```
public List<Object[]> RunQuery(string server, string database, string queryName)
{
    List<Object[]> rows = new List<Object[]>();
    using (SqlConnection conn = createSqlConnection(server))
    {
        SqlCommand comm = conn.CreateCommand();
        comm.CommandText = buildSelect(queryName, database);
        using (SqlDataReader dr = comm.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                if (dr != null && !dr.IsDBNull(0))
                {
                    Object[] row = new Object[dr.FieldCount];
                    int numOfFields = dr.GetValues(row);
                    rows.Add(row);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return rows;
}

public static string buildSelect(string name, string database)
{
    List<Object> res = new List<Object>();
    string query = "";
    using (SqlConnection conn = createSqlConnection(sysServer))
    {
        query = "SELECT TABLE_NAME, FIELDS, CONDITIONS FROM " + sysDb + ".dbo.SolutionQuery WHERE QUERY_NAME LIKE '" + name + "' AND FK_SOLUTION_NAME LIKE 'Portrait Dialogue'";
        SqlCommand comm = conn.CreateCommand();
        comm.CommandText = query;
        using (SqlDataReader dr = comm.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (dr.Read()) if (dr != null && !dr.IsDBNull(0)) for (int i = 0; i < dr.FieldCount; i++) res.Add(dr.GetValue(i));
        }
    }
    foreach (var r in res) Debug.WriteLine("DATA SELECTION ROW: " + r);
    //query = "SELECT " + res[0] + " FROM " + database + res[1] + " " + res[2];
    if (query.Contains("**DB**")) query = query.Replace("**DB**", database);
        return query;
}
```

I'm calling it here

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/solutionquery/runQuery/{server}/{database}/{queryName}")]
public List<Object[]> RunQuery(string server, string database, string queryName)
{
    SolutionRepository repo = new SolutionRepository();
    List<Object[]> res = repo.RunQuery(server, database, queryName);
    return res;
}
```

Here's how I make the connection string (it's an extension method)

```
public static SqlConnection createSqlConnection(string server)
{
    string cs = "Server=" + server + ";Integrated Security=true;";
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cs);
    conn.Open();
    Debug.WriteLine("connection");
    return conn;
}
```

Edit: I do not use Entity Framework

Comment: Seems like  sql error and not a .net error. to make sure, try to run the queryName directly on the sql server using SSMS or SQLCMD see if you get the same error. if it works fine there, then I will try to help you if I can.

Comment: It works absolutely fine in SSMS

Comment: Try to enable [MARS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/h32h3abf(v=vs.110).aspx). Basically you have to add `MultipleActiveResultSets=True` to your connectionstring

Comment: When you try it in SSMS are you logged in with the same user as the one you use on the web? Could be a permission error.

Comment: MARS didn't do it. As for permission everything goes through Windows authentication.

Comment: Explain how you run it in SSMS? You use dynamic SQL without parameters ... Run sql server profiler, find your query and copy it to SSMS.

Comment: It's better to write a stored procedure and run it

Comment: When I run it in SSMS I run the query that code builds, e.g. `SELECT TABLE_NAME, FIELDS, CONDITIONS FROM WebTools2.dbo.SolutionQuery WHERE QUERY_NAME LIKE 'details' AND FK_SOLUTION_NAME LIKE 'Portrait Dialogue'`. I'm not using a stored procedure because the query needs to be editable via. the client later on, and it seems like a simpler solution to me.

Comment: When I run queries outside of the buildSelect method everything is fine, so it's somewhere in there.

Comment: Please read article about dynamic SQL: http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html .It doen't help you with your problem, but it can help to improve your query.

Comment: What is application pool identity? post a screenshot of your application pools. do you have problems with IIS Express?

Comment: I managed to solve my problem. How exactly is a very good question, I will have to get back with that. Thanks for all the help, I appreciate you guys taking your time to lend a hand.